# IP address geolocation when roaming in EU

Tags: roaming

This is a networking question strictly related to travel.

**Q**: what is my IP address when I connect to a roaming cellular network with my EU SIM card when traveling abroad while in EU? Is it from the local ISP or is it tunnelled to my home ISP? Where is then my IP geolocated?

I need to know this information because some services that I use do filter IPs based on geolocation.

I am asking this because I recall that once I went to the UK (pre-Brexit) I found I could watch all porn I wanted when local SIM cards require you a special subscription for porn. And I did some search and found ["When I'm roaming internationally from my mobile, why am I assigned a US IP address?"](https://www.quora.com/When-Im-roaming-internationally-from-my-mobile-why-am-I-assigned-a-US-IP-address) (but I am no US, so I need to know what about EU)

Comment: It depends on both the home and roaming providers.

Comment: In my experience your IP is in your home country (anecdotal evidence, so just a comment, not an answer).

Answer (score 3):

As xngtng pointed out in his comment, it depends, but at least within the EU/EEA, in most cases, the network traffic is routed via your home provider and for geolocation purposes, it will appear as if you are in your home country.

The reason is btw not that you should have easier acces to porn, but that your home network provider wants to have real time access to traffic volume metering and used to want the ability to throttle your network bandwidth. Since July 2022 network operators are not allowed anymore to apply bandwidth throttling when customers are roaming within the EU/EEA.

Comment: Probably the home ISP wants to `meter` the traffic, as I only have handful GB available

Comment: that didn't used to be the case. Only the billing was routed (iow, the roaming provider bills your provider, who bills you. Routing all actual traffic is not practical, would cause useless network load and latency. Throttling was usually applied anyway because of billing limits (not being allowed to charge roaming fees any longer but still having the extra cost, providers would downgrade available plans for roaming customers to lower their cost to provide the service).

Comment: @jwenting I have just confirmed, at least with my two subscriptions (German and Norwegian) that they both use a home country IP address for Internet access when the SIM cards are roaming.